# Changing cell value formatting

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet that has three columns:

**employee number**

**employee name**

**availability (some already have nothing values)**

What I am trying to do is when the **availability** value changes from a number to nothing the **employee number** and the **employee name** associated with that row gets a strikethrough. 
Also when an **availability** number is added the strikethrough disappears. I would like this code to run when a command button is pressed. As of right now the code runs when the button is pressed but those **availability** values that were already nothing and do not change are getting a strikethrough. Is there a way that only the **availability** values that change to nothing not those that were already nothing can get a strikethrough?
I have written some code below but I have no idea if I am going in the right direction.

```
Sub AircraftChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim watchrange As Range, r As Range, rw As Long
Dim intersectrange As Range, endrow As Long

endrow = Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Set watchrange = Range("E2:E" & endrow)
Set intersectrange = Intersect(Target, watchrange)

If intersectrange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

For Each r In intersectrange
rw = r.Row
If r.Value = "" Then
    Range("B" & rw & ":C" & rw).Font.Strikethrough = True
Else
    Range("B" & rw & ":C" & rw).Font.Strikethrough = False
End If
Next r
End Sub
```

Could someone help me?

Thank you in advance
[image]

Comment: Since you have a command button and want to control the update you're bound to use VBA. But if you want to update the formatting (with or without strikethrough) automatically, then you could also accomplish this with conditional formatting and no VBA code.

Comment: The availability column is manipulated by the user and once the user either adds or deletes a number in the availability value I want to hit the command button and the employee name and number will either get a strikethrough or have one removed or if nothing changes nothing happens to the employee number and ID

Comment: I have added a picture of the file I am using... You can see the availability values are those numbers in the 4th column... so what I want to happen is if any of those values that are shown changes to nothing they get crossed out or if a value is added the strikethrough goes away... but those at the bottom in the green and orange that do not have a availability value I do not want these to get a strikethrough because they never change.. I just need those value that change from something to nothing or from nothing to something

Comment: If you want to compare to a previous value (when pressing the button) then you need to know the previous value. So, you'll have to copy the table to another (hidden) sheet. Then someone can press the button and you can compare the two lists and see if something has changed.

Comment: Use the conditional formatting as suggested by @Ralph: it will automatically update the font property (or any other property) depends on the condition you set (no need for VBA). Best regards,

Comment: I cant use conditional formatting because the worksheet that needs the formatting is being pulled in daily to the workbook that holds all the code

Comment: Please refer to my answer posted below. Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Pertinent to your question, the task can be completed in VBA using Array to store the previous values in Column D like shown in the following code snippet:

```
Dim ColumArray(65000) As String

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Target.Column = 4 Then
        ThisRow = Target.Row
        If Target.Value = "" And ColumArray(ThisRow) <> "" Then
            Range("B" & ThisRow & ":C" & ThisRow).Font.Strikethrough = True
        Else
            Range("B" & ThisRow & ":C" & ThisRow).Font.Strikethrough = False
        End If
        ColumArray(ThisRow) = Target.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that this procedure does not require Button event: it will run automatically on any change in Column "D". Alternatively, you can encapsulate it into your Sub `AircraftChange(ByVal Target As Range)` and run it on Button click event. Also, you can set the max index of the array ColumArray(65000) pertinent to the Column "B" last row (as per your code: endrow = Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row ).

The most universal solution (though a bit longer) would be create a global array placed in added Excel VBA code module (e.g. Module1) to store the values of, for example, `Worksheet(1)` Column "D" on `Workbook_Open`, and add the Sub procedure like shown above to the Worksheet(1).

Hope this may help.